# Undocumented options for "BalloonEmbedding" in GraphLayout

Tags: undocumented, graphs-and-networks

From an error message, I see some options of the `BalloonEmbedding` method for `GraphLayout`:

```
Graph::moptx: Method option xxx in BalloonLayout is not one of {AngleSpacing, EvenAngle, OptimalOrder, RootVertex, Rotation, SectorAngles, VertexSize}
```

`EvenAngle`, `OptimalOrder`, `RootVertex`, and `SectorAngles` are mentioned [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphLayout.html#sssOuter0). But can anyone give introductions to `AngleSpacing`, `Rotation`, and `VertexSize`? I am reproducing the layout in the paper [*Interactive data mining with 3D-parallel-coordinate-trees*](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2463696). Telling from the name, I guess `BalloonEmbedding`+ `AngleSpacing` may be close:

[image]

[image]

One additional question, does `BalloonEmbedding` try to preserve the edge weights (distances)? Thank you.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, thanks.